# Jquery for each element in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have got this php code

```
            $notification_list .= "<form id='Rejecat' onSubmit='return false;' >
<input value='Reject' type='submit' id='Reject'>
        </form>
          <form onSubmit='return false;' id='Accepta'>
    <input type='submit' id='Accept' value='Accept'></form></div>";
```

And this jquery code

```
  $("#Reject").click(function(){
    $('#Reject').animate({"margin-left": "-320px"}, 500, function(){
    $('#Reject').css("visibility", "hidden");});
    $('#Accept').animate({"margin-left": "-320px"}, 500, function(){
    $('#Accept').css("visibility", "hidden");});
 }); });
```

When i have for example 2 notifications it works only with first two inputs.How can i make it work with both of them

Comment: can you post the resulting html segment from your php?

Comment: @devlincarnate too long.You can get it from demo

Comment: i asked for it because i suspected that you didn't have unique ids, which will cause problems because it's invalid html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** Ids must be unique

**2nd :** you can use classes

**in php**

```
$notification_list .= "<form class='submitForm Rejecat' onSubmit='return false;' >
<input value='Reject' type='submit' id='Reject'>
        </form>
          <form onSubmit='return false;' class='submitForm Accepta'>
    <input type='submit' id='Accept' value='Accept'></form></div>";
```

**and in js**

```
$('body').on('submit', '.submitForm' , function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var thisone = $(this);
   var getanother = thisone.hasClass('Rejecat') ? thisone.next('form'): thisone.prev('form');

   thisone.animate({"margin-left": "-320px"}, 500, function(){
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
   });
   getanother.animate({"margin-left": "-320px"}, 500, function(){
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
   });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/betsdm3z/)

Comment: I checked your code it did not work it does the same thing

Comment: @MuradMurader did you try a working demo in my answer??

Comment: Yes i copied everything in demo now it is working.Thx